# Unresolved reference inside a nested class Kotlin

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, private

I have an activity with a variable controller and an nested class A. Inside the A class i want to have access to the controller variable. Hoe can i do this?

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

   private val controller: MyController

   ....methods of activity...

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        controller = Controller()
        // Doing stuff
   }


   private class MyListener internal constructor(x: Int): LocalClass.Listener {

      override fun onCallOne() {
           // I get an unresolved reference here
           controller.method()
      }

      override fun onCallTwo() {}

      override fun onCallThree() {}

   }

}
```

The above code is made out of AndroidStudio autoconversion when i pasted the same from Java code, where the controller variable is accessible from the nested class MyListener

Answer (score 3):

I have found it. 
The answer is that i have to make the MyListener class as inner
So the correct declaration is

```
private inner class MyListener internal constructor(x: Int)...
```

Comment: Otherwise if you don't want to use the inner you can also use `this@MyActivity.method()` as well.

Comment: Not true. A non-`inner` class has no associated outer class instance to reference. `this@` syntax is only for resolving ambiguous scope.